# How do I combine and Split text using delimiter :

Tags: text, text-editor, emeditor

I have this text file that Looks like this: 
Firstpart:Secondpart
Firstpart:Secondpart
Firstpart:Secondpart
Firstpart:Secondpart

I want to be able to separate these make changes to the second part and join them back together.

Comment: Each Firstpart:Second Part is on a separate line btw

Answer (score 0):

This is a super late answer but if you would still like to know:

1. Go to Tools | Customize... | CSV
2. Add a new CSV format, where you can change the delimiter.
3. Use the CSV/Sort toolbar to change CSV formats